# How to stop generating multiple RegistrationIds for the same DeviceToken in Azure Notification Hubs?

Tags: azure, push-notification, notifications, azure-notificationhub

When using Notification Hub:

```
var registration1 = await hub.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(cordovaDeviceToken);
var registration2 = await hub.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(cordovaDeviceToken);
```

Why is this creating two different registrations in the hub when it's the same deviceToken?

How do I know if a device token is already registered or not?

I can save the cordovaDeviceToken myself and check on that, but I would assume NotificationHub is arranging that for me.

Why would you want two registrationIds for the same device?

I'm looking for a simple example to achieve a RegisterOrUpdate without creating my own database?

Answer (score 0):

> var registration1 = await hub.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(cordovaDeviceToken);

Based on your code, I assumed that you manage the registrations in your backend.

> How do I know if a device token is already registered or not?

You could leverage [GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.getregistrationsbychannelasync?view=azure-dotnet) to get the registrations based on your `cordovaDeviceToken` to check whether the current deviceToken has been registered or not. Or you could just use [DeleteRegistrationsByChannelAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.deleteregistrationsbychannelasync?view=azure-dotnet) to delete the registrations based on your deviceToken before you create the new registration.

**Note:** The `top` parameter for `GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync` represents the number of registrations return in a single request, the maximum number is 100 and you could use the `continuationToken` from the response for acquiring the next page of registrations.

> Why would you want two registrationIds for the same device?

Per my understanding, a single registration for a deviceToken is enough, the related SDK does not check the existence of the same pnsHandle, you need to explicitly check it in your code.

> I'm looking for a simple example to achieve a RegisterOrUpdate without creating my own database?

You could follow [Tutorial: Send notifications to specific users by using Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification#register-for-notifications-by-using-the-webapi-backend) for the relevant code snippet.